# PowerShell to remove SharePoint subsite permission levels alone

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-on-prem

Looking for a help in getting a PowerShell script to remove SharePoint subsite permissions alone. The groups should exist and users under the groups also. The script should only remove the permission levels assigned to the groups and the users directly added. We need to remove permissions of subsites from different site collections.

Can someone help me with this script please?

Thanks

Comment: can you explain further ? somehow your question is not clear enough to let us think and suggest you a solution

Comment: @AIMENBOULAHIA Thanks for your response. We have over 500 subsites which are from different site collections and we have to remove only the permission levels assigned to the groups and users which are added directly to the sites and not to delete the groups and users under the them. Please let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: Alright, you want to remove permission levels assigned to the groups and users there, and replace them with what ?

Comment: Don't want to replace with any other permission levels, just remove all permissions assigned.